# Перегрузка функции через макрос, предупреждение в _Generic на каст перекрестно

Tags: c, препроцессор, c11

Есть код, в котором происходит перегрузка функции через макрос.

Компилятор выдаёт предупреждение на каст переменных, но скомпилированная программа работает правильно.
Подавление предупреждений не вариант.

**Хотелось бы знать причину предупреждений, это стандартное поведение или несовершенство препроцессора?**

Минимальный код для проверки и экспериментов.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 
#define FNK(...) \
        FFF_x(, \
                ##__VA_ARGS__, \
                FFF_B(__VA_ARGS__), \
                FFF_A(__VA_ARGS__), \
                FFF_0(__VA_ARGS__))
 
#define FFF_x(x, A, B, FFF, ...)FFF
 
#define FFF_0() fnk(0, 0, NULL)
#define FFF_A(A) fnk(A, 0, NULL)
 
#define FFF_B(A, BC) \
        _Generic((A), \
                int : _Generic((BC), \
                        int : fnk(A, BC, NULL), \
                        char * : fnk(A, 0, BC)))
 
void fnk(uintmax_t A, uintmax_t B, char* C){
    printf("A : %"PRIXMAX"\n", A);
    printf("B : %"PRIXMAX"\n", B);
    printf("C : \"%s\"\n", C);
}
 
void fnk_test(void){
    printf("\n0)---------\n");
    FNK();
 
    printf("\n1)---------\n");
    FNK(1);
 
    printf("\n2.1)---------\n");
    FNK(1, 2);
 
    printf("\n2.2)---------\n");
    FNK(1, "2");
}
 
int main() {
    fnk_test();
    return 0;
}
```

В FNK(1, 2); -- ругается на то, что переменная не char *
,а
в FNK(1, "2"); -- наоборот, что не int.

Вывод программы:

```
0)---------
A : 0
B : 0
C : "(null)"
 
1)---------
A : 1
B : 0
C : "(null)"
 
2.1)---------
A : 1
B : 2
C : "(null)"
 
2.2)---------
A : 1
B : 0
C : "2"
```

Предупреждения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: _Generic был добавлен в с11, с99 метка тут ни к чему

Comment: @PR-Zz пример не воспроизводится на компилятор gcc 9.2 `error: expected expression before ‘,’ token    #define FFF_A(A)   fnk( A, 0, NULL)`  ругается на запятую после ` fnk( A, `

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть код после препроцессинга https://stackoverflow.com/q/277258/13970074

Comment: [Вот](https://godbolt.org/z/r64xG4) пара примеров попроще. Предупреждение выдают и gcc и clang. При этом gcc ещё и генерирует несколько сомнительный код, закидывая адрес строки в `edi` вместо `rdi` (хотя может это не баг, а хитрая оптимизация). Похоже у `_Generic`'а какая-то проблема с сопоставлением `char *`, но правы ли здесь компиляторы, ругаясь на код, я сказать не могу...

Comment: Пролиистал багзиллу — конкретно этой проблемы нет, но в `gcc` несколько багов о том что многие предупреждения относятся к мёртвому коду, ближайшее к сабжу, пожалуй, [это](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68193). Так что я бы сказал, что это баг... Что там с clang'ом мне смотреть лень, но скорей всего проблема аналогичная — предупреждение выписывается раньше, чем компилятор догадывается, что код недостижим.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, _rdi_ от _edi_ отличается только разрядностью. Если компилятор гарантирует, что старшие биты либо не меняются, либо всегда нолики, то замена вполне адекватная.

Comment: @0andriy, это понятно... я и говорю, что не знаю гарантируется ли ABI GNU/Linux (подразумевая, что на godbolt'е компилятор под него), что `.rodata` будет загружена в нижнюю память...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Решение:

```
#define INT_OR_0(A) _Generic((A), int: (A), default: 0)
#define CHARP_OR_NULL(A) _Generic((A), char *:(A), default: NULL)

#define FFF_B(A, BC) \
        _Generic((A), \
                int : _Generic((BC), \
                        int : fnk(A, INT_OR_0(BC), NULL), \
                        char * : fnk(A, 0, CHARP_OR_NULL(BC))))
```

Подробнее тут: https://qna.habr.com/q/816309